# How to properly cast an object?

Tags: c++

I have a code,

```
class foo : public bar
{
 public:
    foo(){};
    ~foo(){};
};

class wu
{
 public:
    wu(const bar& Bar ) :
       m_bar(Bar)
    {};
    ~wu(){};

 private:
    bar m_bar;

};

int main()
{
    foo tmpFoo;
    wu tmpWu(tmpFoo);
}
```

Now my problem is, the code above will not compile and the error message is "error: variable wu tmpWu has initializer but incomplete type".

Does it mean, I have to cast the tmpFoo object to bar class?

Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the full code? This can't compile without `bar` being defined.

Comment: You are getting error with the edited piece of code also? (assuming `bar` class is already defined)

Comment: yes, its not the full or the actual code, but the same logic.

Comment: it compiles properly if you define `bar` class. You have done that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the syntax `m_bar(Bar)` instead of `m_bar = Bar` in the `wu` class constructor. Also, remove the braces from the `tmpFoo` variable declaration, otherwise you will be declaring a function that returns a `foo` object and receives no arguments.

---

After your edit: I tried that code, and the problem it gave was that the `bar` class was undefined. In your case, the compiler gave an "incomplete type" error; that means that somewhere in an included file (or in the same file), the class `bar` is declared this way:

```
class bar;
```

but it is never defined its contents.

Comment: Thank your very much, but please assume the the bar was defined.

Answer (score 4):

adding

```
class bar {};
```

your code works for me. Am I missing something?